# Case of "more" and "else"

Tags: word-usage, word-difference, word-in-context

I know that both "**more**" and "**else**" can be used in the meaning of "**besides**". Well, at least I think so. Here are examples:

1. I have told you all I know. What else do you want with me?
2. I have told you all I know. What more do you want with me?

As far as I am aware, the later is less common but carries the same meaning as the former sentence.

For this not to sound like a duplicate, here's the main question: Can "**else**" and "**more**' work in an identical way in the following sentences with the words "**anything, something, whatever, whenever, wherever, whomever, whoever, someone, somebody, and everything**"?

- I've already helped your mom and sister. Is there anyone more you want me to help?
- That's it. I can't help him. There's nothing more I can do!

Edit: It's not a duplicate. I'm not asking about the difference between "**what else**" and "**what more**". I'm asking about using "**else**" and "**more**" with words "**anything, something, whatever, whenever, wherever, whomever, whoever, someone, somebody, and everything**".

Comment: want **from** me

Comment: @MvLog - "What do you want from/of/with me?" - all these prepositions are possible. [See here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+want+of+me%2Cyou+want+from+me%2Cyou+want+with+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20want%20of%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20want%20from%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20want%20with%20me%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Rompey  In the examples provided **from** is the most probable case. **With** just sounds archaic; we can see that on the graph you've linked.

Comment: I guess there's not a person here who knows how this works so he can tell me, right?

Comment: It's not a duplicate, reread the question attentively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first couple of sentences, refer to the suggested other question...

Referring to the rest of the questions:

In the first case, "more" is incorrect (although it would be understood). *Your mom and sister are different entities*.

> I've already helped your mom and sister. Is there anyone <s>more</s> else you want me to help?

But it could be used in a slightly different phrasing, if the family is thought of as group of people:

> Do you have more family members you want me to help?

---

In the second case, "more" is correct, suggesting that you did some things to help but you can't do more things (nothing more).

> That's it. I can't help him. There's nothing more I can do.

In this case "else" would be correct if specific actions were listed:

> I gave him a map, showed him the place and suggested a path. There's nothing else I can do.

But "more" would also be correct, as it suggests "more help".